# GROUP BY on multiple columns with multiple INNER JOINs

Tags: mysql

I have a simple select query which joins 5 tables together to get information. I want the distinct values from two columns on two different tables, not a distinct combination of the values from two columns.

**Community Table**

```
+--------+----+------------------+-----------------+------+
| title  | id | shortdescription | longdescription | type |
+--------+----+------------------+-----------------+------+
| Sci-fi | 14 | Lorem ipsum      | Lorem ipsum     | mix  |
+--------+----+------------------+-----------------+------+
```

**Community Tag Categories Table:**

```
+-----------+----------+
| community | category |
+-----------+----------+
|        14 |        5 |
|        14 |        9 |
|        14 |       17 |
|        14 |       18 |
+-----------+----------+
```

**Tag Category Table**

```
+-----------+----+
| category  | id |
+-----------+----+
| character |  5 |
| warning   |  9 |
| mention   | 17 |
| focus     | 18 |
+-----------+----+
```

**Community Tags Table:**

```
+-----------+-----+
| community | tag |
+-----------+-----+
|        14 | 136 |
|        14 | 137 |
|        14 | 138 |
|        14 | 139 |
+-----------+-----+
```

**Tags Table:**

```
+--------+-----+
|  name  | id  |
+--------+-----+
| sci-fi | 136 |
| space  | 137 |
| aliens | 138 |
| future | 139 |
+--------+-----+
```

This is the query I've been trying:

```
SELECT c.title, c.id, c.shortdescription, c.longdescription, c.type, tc.category, t.name AS 'tag'
FROM Community c, CommunityTagCategories cc, TagCategory tc, CommunityTags ct, Tag t
WHERE c.id=cc.community
AND cc.category=tc.id
AND ct.tag=t.id
AND c.id=ct.community
AND c.id=14;
```

`Community 14` has `4 tag` categories and 4 tags and I would ideally like 4 results to be returned. However it returns 16 results because it's giving me all the possible combinations for tag categories and tags.

Result I want to see (with info from community table truncated for space):

```
+-------------------------+--------------+-----------+
|    community columns    | tag category |    tag    |
+-------------------------+--------------+-----------+
| community info repeated | sci-fi       | character |
| community info repeated | space        | warning   |
| community info repeated | aliens       | mention   |
| community info repeated | future       | focus     |
+-------------------------+--------------+-----------+
```

If I use `"GROUP BY t.id"` this returns the `4 tags`, but it only returns one tag category repeated four times (vice versa with `"GROUP BY tc.id"`).

If I use a comma as in `"GROUP BY tc.id, t.id"` then it returns `16` results again.

`"GROUP BY tc.id AND t.id"` returns nothing.

Is there a way to only get 4 rows for the 4 tag categories and 4 tags?

Comment: Maybe if you post sample data and expected results you will understand better what you really want, so will we.

Comment: Implicit "comma" join notation has been out of favor for around two decades now; at this point using it for all but the simplest queries is archaic. Explicit JOINs are considering easier to read and maintain. It doesn't look like you have anything actually joining tags to categories.

Comment: @forpas Does this help?

Comment: @Uueerdo There's no relationship between tags and categories, the tags relate to the community and the categories relate to the community.

Comment: Please post sone example data for the original tables that should rfinish in to your desired result

Comment: Without a relation between tags and categories, there is really no way to get what you want short of manufacturing "row numbers" in subqueries and using those as join criteria, and then you'd have to deal with when there are more tags than categories, or more categories than tags, separately. This is something better handled as multiple queries for data, and presentation handled client side.

Comment: @Uueerdo Thank you. I didn't realise it wasn't possible in a single query. I'll just have to do two queries then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a relation between tags and categories, there is really no way to get what you want short of manufacturing "row numbers" in subqueries and using those as join criteria, and then you'd have to deal with when there are more tags than categories, or more categories than tags, separately (since MySQL still doesn't have a FULL OUTER JOIN).

This is something better handled as multiple queries for data, and then presentation handled client side.